# What is the Most Efficient Way to Nest Classes/Objects in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm learning C# after working in JavaScript for about a year. OOP wasn't my strong suit. Now that I'm using an OOP language, I'm curious if there's a cleaner way to nest classes in C#. For example, in JavaScript (wrong or right), I would have done this.

```
class Person {
  constructor(firstName,lastName,address){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = {
      street: address.street,
      city: address.city,
      state: address.state,
      zip: address.zip
    }
  }
}
```

In C#, it seems like I have to do this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

It's not the end of the world if there's not a cleaner way. This is just my curiosity.

For example, let's say I will only ever add an Address when it's attached to a Person. The C# code makes it possible to create an instance of Address without it belonging to a Person.

To be fair, I know the JS isn't preventing that either and I understand that.

Comment: JavaScript and C# are completely different languages, with completely different design goals. Bottom line: in C# you have to explicitly declare types and their members. You'll need to get over "not liking" particulars of language mechanics. (For web development, you can use TypeScript, which has C#-like features but also JavaScript-like features...but this isn't available for general-purpose app development.)

Comment: Do note that there is one exception: in C#, there are anonymous types and value type tuples (the latter is new to C# 7) which, in the context of a method only, allow implicit declaration of complex container types with named properties and fields (for anonymous types and tuples, respectively). There's not enough context in your question to know if that would suit your particular need. Those features are available, but definitely very situation-specific.

Comment: Nothing to get over. :) Just making sure that I'm doing things logically. Updating question to elaborate a little.

Comment: What it seems like you have to do is actually what is recommended to do but not what you "have to".  However; IMO and probably the opinion of many other C# devs at least, that is clean and preferred.  So, if I may suggest, doing it that way, even in JavaScript, is recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you done it fine! after that you can init the object like:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person
        {
            Name = "Jone",
            Address = new Address
            {
                Street = "Highway",
                City = "New York",
                Zip = "15",
                State = "other"
            }
        };

    }
```